# Python 3 urllib.request byte indicator b' causing issues

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I have a variable storing random characters which may be special chars that came from decoding base64:

```
variable = qb'l*,707$}p*yk
```

And i append that onto the end of a URL I already know to navigate a specific page
www.website.com/1/2/3/index.php?addafterthis=

So I try to open like this:

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.open('www.website.com/1/2/3/index.php?addafterthis=',str.encode(string))
```

I believe str.encode adds b' to represent bytes
and you end up with
addafterthis= b'qb'l*,707$}p*yk

instead of the correct

addafterthis=qb'l*,707$}p*yk

However I cant remove the str.encode option or I get the error
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Wrong encoding/ wrong way of encoding, wrong way of opening the page with urllib?

Comment: I cannot make any sense out of your string variable. Can you post the actual string and where it comes from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str.encode` is certainly wrong. The object you're passing is a `bytes` instance, not a `str` instance, so the `str` type's `encode` method will raise an exception.

I suspect you wanted to use `urllib.parse.urlencode`. This takes a mapping or sequence of 2-tuples and produces a query string suitable for using in a HTTP request. Try this:

```
query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({'addafterthis':string})
opener.open('www.website.com/1/2/3/index.php?{}'.format(query_string))
```

Note that this does a HTTP `GET` request, since the query string is built right into the URL. If you wanted to do a `POST` request instead, you'd need to call `open` with the data as a separate parameter (and it would need to be encoded as `bytes`):

```
opener.open('www.website.com/1/2/3/index.php', query_string.encode())
```

Comment: This worked! I was reading over the urllib.parse.urlencode documentation but they didnt have any examples. Was very helpful to have an actual working example to understand how it works. Thanks!

Comment: My examples were written after checking out the [`urllib` examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib-examples) section of the docs (which were linked to by the `urllib.parse.urlencode` docs). You might want to read them too!

Comment: Reading over that. I dont understand the end of the open part {}'.format(answer)) is a little confusing Ill try to see if I can find something so I better understand that.

Comment: @Shiroslullaby: That's just basic string formatting. Since the query string goes at the end you could also just use `+` to concatenate the strings.